# remove curly braces in json encode

Tags: php, json, curl

I have an API which has the request of this form.
`stb_list:{"1":{"stb":"SDA4C123456790"}}`

and here's my code in PHP:

```
$data1=array('stb' => 'SDA4C123456789');

$data2=array('1'=> $data1);

$data_array=array('stb_list'=>$data2);

$data_string=json_encode($data_array);

echo $data_string;
```

which gives this output: `{"stb_list":{"1":{"stb":"SDA4C123456789"}}}`

Now, I am really stuck with this for a while as the API provider has refused to guide me on this. I have tried all available options but couldn't frame a request of that form. So please help out in solving this issue and in learning something new.

Comment: leaving first and last character from the string leaves me with this. `"stb_list":{"1"}....`

Comment: right, didn't notice you didn't want the quotes around `stb_list`

Comment: yes sir, i don't want the quotes. I don't know whether I am doing something wrong or the mistake is from his end.